# How to render HTML and Rails helpers in a Devise flash message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to render a custom flash message from a Devise controller.

It is being rendered in the view as follows:

```
<strong>Your profile is incomplete.</strong> Why not #{ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to 'add some more information', edit_user_registration_path}.
```

How do I render HTML and Rails helpers in this flash?

I'm calling the flash in the controller

```
set_flash_message :warning, :profile_incomplete
```

With `:profile_incomplete` defined in config/locales/devise.en.yml.

I tried putting the string directly in the controller. This correctly renders the helper, but instead displays a Devise translation not found error.

I have tried appending `.html_safe` in devise.en.yml, which causes a yaml error. I've tried appending to `:profile_incomplete` which causes `undefined method 'html_safe' for :profile_incomplete:Symbol`. And I've tried appending to the plain string, which didn't seem to do anything.

What am I missing? Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT

sessions_controller.rb

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)

  if current_user.completeness < 100
    set_flash_message :alert, :profile_incomplete, :link => ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to('add some more information', edit_user_registration_path)
  end

end
```

devise.en.yml

```
en:
  devise:
    sessions:
      profile_incomplete:"<strong>Your profile is incomplete.</strong> Why not #{link}."
```

application.html.erb

```
<% flash.each do |key, msg| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</a>
        <%= msg.html_safe %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the source of set_flash_message: https://github.com/rymai/devise_invitable/blob/master/lib/devise_invitable/controllers/internal_helpers.rb#L5

You cannot add methods in i18n files .. just named interpolations. My solution for your problem is:

```
set_flash_message :warning, :profile_incomplete, :link => link_to('add some more information', edit_user_registration_path)
```

and in devise.en.yml

```
...
profile_incomplete: "<strong>Your profile is incomplete.</strong> Why not %{link}"
```

also when displaying the flash message (probably in application.html.erb/haml) add a html_safe at the end of each flash message

Comment: thanks BCD, this makes a lot of sense. But I'm hitting a small issue. Using your code directly I get `undefined method 'link_to' for #<Users::SessionsController:...`. If I modify your code to use `ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to...` then Rails renders `Why not %{link}`. How can I get the link_to helper working in teh controller?

Comment: Because link_to is a helper made available for views (I missed that :| ). You can use it with ActionController::Base.helpers  ...

Comment: Thanks bcd. But when I do this the view displays %{link}. It is not converted to the passed variable. Any idea why?

Comment: Added the relevant bits above. Do you need anything else?

Comment: In devise.en.yml do you have #{link} or %{link}. What the exact output in the browser?

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Sorry, should have spotted that I had typed `#{link}` when I needed `%{link}`. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Sorry where do you set the set_flash_message :warning, :profile_incomplete, :link => link_to('add some more information', edit_user_registration_path)