# Adding Links to Devise Flash Messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to be able to append a "Resend confirmation email?" link in this particular portion of [devise.en.yml](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml):

```
en:
  devise:
    failure:
      unconfirmed: "You have to confirm your email address before continuing.
```

As per research, it appears this can be done via two ways: [name interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622547/how-to-render-html-and-rails-helpers-in-a-devise-flash-message) and [html_safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008059/rails-devise-customize-flash-message-devise-en-yml-with-a-link-to), however both only seem to apply to messages under controllers than can be overridden.

Am I correct in observing that the message in question is not managed by a controller, but by [failure_app.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/dd5de829c944dd955e4b35074c60798c3ad4b947/lib/devise/failure_app.rb) instead? I tried the above in [sessions_controller.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb) and [confirmations_controller.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb) to no avail.

As such, do I need to override `failure_app.rb` instead? If so, how do I go about doing this? I believe something like `warden_message == :unconfirmed` is the only thing I need to flag the error, but I do not know which method is responsible for catching `:unconfirmed`.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
# app/views/home/index.html.erb
<%=t 'greet_username', user: "Bill", message: "Goodbye" %>

# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  greet_username: "%{message}, %{user}!"
```

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations

---

You might also need to override any of the devise views.

Comment: As I kind of expected, an error was thrown: "I18n::MissingInterpolationArgument".